# How do I change a web site from an IIS hosted site to an ASP.Net Development Server hosted site?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6, asp.net-development-serv

On my previous machine I had IIS6 installed and created a web project using IIS as the host. This project was completed, published to an internal hosting server and checked in to source control.

I now need to go back and make a minor change to the project, however in the meantime I have acquired a new machine. On my new machine I don’t have IIS – and don’t really have any wish to go back to using IIS as I find the ASP.Net development server sufficient for my needs.

I can’t open the project at all in Visual Studio without becoming an Administrator and installing IIS 6. Is there some way I can modify the project and solution files to make it play nicely and use the ASP.Net development server instead?

**EDIT:** additional info, this was created as a **web site** not a **web project** so there is no .csproj file.

Version info: Visual Studio 2008, .net 3.5.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you start a new project and use the "Use Custom Web Server" option?

Personally I would start a new project and get the files directly from Source Control - being a web site rather than project you shouldn't run into any problems and whilst you only need to make a minor change now you may well need to make more minor changes in the future so having quick and ready access to the source will likely be useful.

Comment: Thanks for this. In the end I recreated it as a web application rather than another web site as I may need that flexibility in future - and manually copied the files across from source control. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Web Site project (no .proj file, no pre-compilation of the project code into a dll) you can try the following:

Open the .sln file in a text editor of choice, and in the "ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties)" add the following line:

```
VWDPort = "xxxx"
```

Where xxxx is a random port number that's not in use - this seems to be the only differnce between using a proper server and using the development server.

If it was a Web Application Project you could try the following:

Open the .proj file in a text editor of choice, and modify the WebProjectProperties:

False
    True
    0
    /
    
    
    False

That might get you going.

Comment: Changing this didn't seem to work. I think there are more differences in the .sln files ProjectSection than just that. In the end I went for a new project. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No probs - I did a compare (with a 2008 solution), and this was the only difference in the .sln file. There were some other differences in the file locations between 2005 and 2008, and the version numbers which I guess could also account for it, but the main thing was the VWDPort addition.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, it seems you can run the Development server stand alone:

http://blog.sb2.fr/post/2008/11/28/Use-Microsoft-NET-ASPNET-Development-Server-Standalone.aspx